Type mismatch error in Excel when trying to select table data
I'm trying to select the DataBodyRange of a column in a table through VBA, and I get a

"Type Mismatch" (error 13)

with a line such as:
Sheet4.ListObjects("InspectionsPassees").ListColumns("Nom").DataBodyRange

I've checked and rechecked the names of the table and column, no problem there. I initially had this long XLookup formula that threw the Type Mismatch error, so I started breaking it down into smaller pieces, and realized that the line above was the problem. By the way, same error with:
Sheet4.ListObjects("InspectionsPassees").ListColumns("Nom").Range

But:
MsgBox(Sheet4.ListObjects("InspectionsPassees").ListColumns("Nom").Range.Count)

will happily display 66 without a problem.
I don't get it...
Any help will be greatly appreciated!
NB: The XLookup snippet that threw the error looked like that:
Dim ip As ListObject
Dim nom As Range, prenom As Range, nomJF As Range, DOB As Range, inspP As Range
Set ip = Sheet4.ListObjects("InspectionsPassees")
Set nom = ip.ListColumns("Nom").DataBodyRange
Set prenom = ip.ListColumns("Prenom").DataBodyRange
Set nomJF = ip.ListColumns("Nom_JF").DataBodyRange
Set DOB = ip.ListColumns("Date_naissance").DataBodyRange
Set inspP = ip.ListColumns("À revoir").DataBodyRange
With Sheet3.ListObjects("Contractuels")
    For Each Cx In .ListRows
        If Application.Intersect(Cx.Range, .ListColumns("Cx").Range) = "C0" Then
            Application.Intersect(Cx.Range, .ListColumns("Insp").Range) = "VC"
        ElseIf Application.XLookup(1, nom = Application.Intersect(Cx.Range, .ListColumns("Nom").Range), inspP) = "oui" Then
            Application.Intersect(Cx.Range, .ListColumns("Insp").Range) = "INSP"
        Else: Application.Intersect(Cx.Range, .ListColumns("Insp").Range) = "non"
        End If
    Next Cx
End With

[knowing that the point was to use boolean logic and multiply the criteria in the XLOOKUP formula (hence the definitions for all the columns, but I shortened it to analyzing one column for the sake of example...)]
EDIT (as per @VBasic2008's suggestion in the comments):
I am importing a list of people from PowerQuery (Sheet3.ListObjects("Contractuels")). Some are newly employed by us, some we previously already employed, and consequently have a "history" with us. For those people (already employed), if they haven't been visited on site yet, they must be, and if they already have, there's another table (Sheet4.ListObjects("InspectionsPassees")) listing identities, and whether they must be seen again (depending on how the first visit actually went). The XLOOKUP formula I was trying to implement in VBA in fact imports that "historical" data into the first table [Contractuels in Sheet3], which lists everyone we employ). The formula is supposed to match people based on several columns: last, first, and maiden name, plus date of birth (hence the boolean logic in the XLOOKUP formula). I tried writing the formula in Excel directly, and it works, but it's never-ending (because of the number of arguments passed to XLOOKUP itself, but also because of the multiple conditions involved...)
I'll try to insert it directly into the cells' ranges, as @Rory suggested: I'm afraid the length is way over 255 characters, so Evaluate (which I don't know, but will be sure to investigate) is out of the question :S

How exactly are you using these 'lines'? For example, you could do Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Sheet4.ListObjects("InspectionsPassees").ListColumns("Nom").DataBodyRange: Debug.Print rg.Address and report what exactly is happening.

Thanks @VBasic2008. I have done what you asked, and gotten the expected result: $A$2:$A$67

You can't compare arrays (or multi-cell ranges) using = in VBA.

Thanks @Rory! This would mean that my XLookup formula is throwing an error because the array compare functionality does not exist in VBA? So, what should I do? Go the route: Range.Formula = "IF(XLOOKUP(etc." or is there a "cleaner" way to do this through code?

It depends entirely on the circumstances. You can use Evaluate and pass a formula string as long as that string is under 255 characters. Or you could just put formulas in the table.

Could you share in your own words what the XLOOKUP is supposed to return and/or at least the Excel formula?

Sure @VBasic2008! Check my edited question!

How does the = "oui" fit into the story?

A simplification, for the sake of example...

Thank you @Rory for the heads-up about arrays not being comparable with = in VBA (which —to be honest— is a shame, since it's such a brilliant and convenient functionality...)
I went the simple way, then, and just literally typed the formula into the cell with Range.Formula = 
The edited snippet therefore now reads as follows:
For Each Cx In .ListRows
    If Application.Intersect(Cx.Range, .ListColumns("Cx").Range) = "C0" Then
        Application.Intersect(Cx.Range, .ListColumns("Insp").Range) = "VC"
    Else: Application.Intersect(Cx.Range, .ListColumns("Insp").Range).Formula = "=IF(IFERROR(XLOOKUP(1, (InspectionsPassees[Nom]=[@Nom])*(InspectionsPassees[Prenom]=[@Prenom])*(InspectionsPassees[Nom_JF]=[@[Nom_JF]])*(InspectionsPassees[Date_naissance]=[@[Date_naissance]]), InspectionsPassees[À revoir]), 0)<>0, XLOOKUP(1, (InspectionsPassees[Nom]=[@Nom])*(InspectionsPassees[Prenom]=[@Prenom])*(InspectionsPassees[Nom_JF]=[@[Nom_JF]])*(InspectionsPassees[Date_naissance]=[@[Date_naissance]]), InspectionsPassees[À revoir]), " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
    End If
Next Cx


Or even better:
Else: Application.Intersect(Cx.Range, .ListColumns("Insp").Range).Formula = "=LET(lookup, XLOOKUP(1, (InspectionsPassees[Nom]=[@Nom])*(InspectionsPassees[Prenom]=[@Prenom])*(InspectionsPassees[Nom_JF]=[@[Nom_JF]])*(InspectionsPassees[Date_naissance]=[@[Date_naissance]]), InspectionsPassees[À revoir]), IF(IFERROR(lookup, 0)<>0, lookup, " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "))"
